# ¿Subconsulta con MAX y YEAR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un problema con una subconsulta me pide

Listar todos los pedidos registrados (pedidoscabe) del último año y del último mes
registrado.

Intente probando con estos comandos

```
SELECT  CAB.* FROM pedidoscabe CAB
WHERE CAB.IdPedido IN ( SELECT c.idPedido FROM pedidoscabe C
WHERE C.FechaPedido IN (YEAR(MAX(c.FechaPedido)),MONTH(MAX(c.FechaPedido)))
)
```

Me sale este error:
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Deberia quedarme asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PSDT: Debo hacerlo con solo subconsultas sin inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como necesitas 2 datos para obtener el último mes (ya sea que uses inicio y fin o año y mes), lo ideal es que la subconsulta funcione como una tabla virtual. Así puedes generar el filtro mediante un JOIN.

```
SELECT  CAB.* 
FROM pedidoscabe CAB
JOIN (SELECT MAX( c.FechaPedido) FechaUltimoPedido
        FROM pedidoscabe c) PC ON CAB.FechaPedido >= DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0,  FechaUltimoPedido), 0) --Mayor o igual al inicio del mes del último pedido
                              AND CAB.FechaPedido <  DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, -1, FechaUltimoPedido), 0) --Menor al inicio del mes despues del último pedido
```

Comment: Luis Cazares , un compa me ayudo asi bro , pero veo q usaste join tambien , claro de que sale si pero con solo subconsultas seria asi,
SELECT  CAB.* FROM pedidoscabe CAB
WHERE CAB.IdPedido IN ( SELECT c.idPedido FROM pedidoscabe C
WHERE YEAR(C.FechaPedido)=(SELECT YEAR(MAX(FechaPedido)) FROM pedidoscabe)
AND MONTH(c.fechapedido)=(SELECT MONTH(MAX(FechaPedido)) FROM pedidoscabe)
Group by c.idPedido
)

Comment: Pero así estás leyendo la tabla 4 veces. Es el doble de lecturas y eso es desperdicio de recursos. Además, el `GROUP BY` es totalmente innecesario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```sql
select cabFinal.*
from ( 
       select cabInt.*
       from pedidoscabe cabInt 
       group cabInt.IdPedido, cabInt.IdCliente, cabInt.IdEmpleado, 
             cabInt.FechaPedido, cabInt.FechaEntrega,
             cabInt.FechaEnvio, cabInt.EnvioPedido, cabInt.CantidadPedido
       having year(cabInt.FechaPedido) = max(year(cabInt.FechaPedido))
     ) cabFinal
group by cabFinal.IdPedido, cabFinal.IdCliente, cabFinal.IdEmpleado, 
         cabFinal.FechaPedido, cabFinal.FechaEntrega,
         cabFinal.FechaEnvio, cabFinal.EnvioPedido, cabFinal.CantidadPedido
having month(cabFinal.FechaPedido) = max(month(cabFinal.FechaPedido))
```

Con la subconsulta obtienes, primero, las ventas basándote en el año máximo y después evalúas el mes máximo.

Comment: Isanchezo salio con esto bro , pero gracias por responder 
SELECT  CAB.* FROM pedidoscabe CAB
WHERE CAB.IdPedido IN ( SELECT c.idPedido FROM pedidoscabe C
WHERE YEAR(C.FechaPedido)=(SELECT YEAR(MAX(FechaPedido)) FROM pedidoscabe)
AND MONTH(c.fechapedido)=(SELECT MONTH(MAX(FechaPedido)) FROM pedidoscabe)
Group by c.idPedido
)